Cannot compile code against latest stable GeoTools/GeoServer version
I've previously successfully compiled a GeoServer extension against earlier GeoServer/GeoTools versions, but today, I'm getting some dependency issues (Java newbie here).
I am trying to build for GeoTools 31.3/GeoServer 2.25.3
The first issue I hit is:
package org.opengis.util does not exist

The failing import is:
import org.opengis.util.InternationalString;

How do I determine whether anything has changed in the last year or so in GeoTools/GeoServer which would result in such an import failing?

The org.opengis packages are gone in GeoTools 30.x, see the upgrade guide for that series: https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/welcome/upgrade.html
Along with the GeoTools 30.0 release announcement, which provides some context:
https://geotoolsnews.blogspot.com/2023/10/geotools-300-released.html

Thank you - the attached remove-opengis.xml ant script looks like it worked perfectly. Thanks to you, Jody, and Ian for the work.
